# Barycenter of a Cartesian Oval from some points

Tags: geometry

I have a list of around 15-20 coordinate pairs (big numbers, around 8 digits each) that belong to a cartesian oval (specifically, they make an egg shape). I have been tasked to find the barycenter of the "full egg".

What should I make in order to find those coordinates of the barycenter? From what I understand, I should find the values for the general equation first, then integrate inside the egg, and then... something something?

Also, supposing that's the right way to do it; which is the easiest course of action, specially considering the size of the numbers involved?

Comment: What do you mean by an "oval"? Do you mean an ellipse?

Comment: As far as I know, "Cartesian Oval" is the right denomination: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_oval)